# what happen if a flux/mono/Observable never be subscribed

Tags: rx-java2, spring-webflux

```java
public void test(){

     Mono<String> mono = Mono.just("aaa")
     FLux<String> flux = Flux.fromArray()    
     Observable<String> observable = Observable.from(...) 

}
```

what happened test method has been executed?

1. all the three object will be collected by GC?
2. if there's some operation, the operation will never be  executed?
3. if the question above is no, what would happened?

Comment: Nothing happens until you subscribe.

Comment: Nothing will happen until you subscribe.

Answer (score 2):

To better understand how Flux and Mono is working, you can imagine them as pipes. When you write code - you are not doing operations on your data, but you only describe what should happen to data when pipe will be complete. To make the pipe complete - you need to subscribe to it (that's the end of the pipe).

For example this code:

```
Mono sampleMono = Mono.just(1)
    .map(Integer::toString)
    .doOnNext(System.out::println)
```

In this code, you only tell, what should be done when someone subscribe to `sampleMono`. when someone do that - then `1` will be emitted, mapped to String and printed to console. But it will happen only after subscribe.

It's something like water pipeline - you can get cold water from well and install water heater. But you newer get warm water until you use shower or sink (you need to subscribe for warm water :) ).

Mono and Flux are lazy - so it will emit only when someone subscribe. Of course - all of the code lines were executed, but they are responsible for creating "pipeline", and until you subscribe - they remain unused. But maybe java with optimizers will do the thing, and these lines will be removed from machine code at all.